# Guidance on unit testing in Python and usage of mock

Tags: python, json, unit-testing

I have a directory whose current structure is:

```
raaj
|_ earth.py
|_ Science.json
|_ testearth.py
```

Inside `Science.json`:

```
{
    "items": [
        "hello"
    ]
}
```

My `earth.py` looks like this:

```
import json

class Foo:
    foo_obj: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_obj = "Raaj"
    
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo_obj

class Bar: 
    bar_obj: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar_obj = "Science.json"

    def get_bar(self):
        return self.bar_obj

class Earth:

    my_name: Foo
    file_path_obj: Bar

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_name = Foo()
        self.file_path_obj = Bar()

    def do_magic(self):
        with open(self.file_path_obj.get_bar(), "rb") as json_file:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)
        names = json_data["items"]
        print(names)
        mung_string = self.my_name.get_foo() + " " +  names[0]

        actual = Earth()
        print(mung_string)
        return "Raaj hello" == mung_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eo = Earth()
    eo.do_magic()
```

For testing, I want to test this function `do_magic` and so I want to be able to mock various values of `mung_string`.
As one can see, since `mung_string` involves concatenating with JSON file string values, I figured I should mock the JSON file and have it return different expected string values.

I'm able to mock out values of class `Foo`. I'm able to mock the JSON file path using mock of class `Bar`. However, I'm stuck figuring out how exactly to achieve this return fake data and have it be routed through `do_magic`. I could use some help figuring out how to go about this.

For reference, this is how my `testearth.py` looks at the moment:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, mock_open
import json
from earth import Earth, Foo, Bar

class TestEarth(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('earth.Bar.get_bar')
    @patch('earth.Foo.get_foo')
    def test_earth_working(self, mock_get_foo, mock_get_bar):
        """
        In this test, several parts exist:
        - I need to test earth class that :
            - returns True or False when do_magic() is executed
            - Mocks JSON and returns modified values to test do_magic()
            - Mocks Foo and Bar to return modified a string representing name, and a string representing JSON file path respectively
        """
        # modify return values of Foo and Bar
        mock_get_foo.return_value = "PV"
        mock_get_bar.return_value = "Science.json"

        # mock JSON
        expected_data = {
                "items": [
                    "PBV"
                    ]
                }
        with patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data=expected_data) as filemock:
            with open("Science.json") as fh:
                mock_json_data = fh.read()
        print("mock JSON:{}".format(mock_json_data))
        filemock.assert_called_with("Science.json")

        earth_obj = Earth()
        expected_mung_string = "PV PBV"
        expected_output = False
        actual_output = earth_obj.do_magic()  # mung_string to pass = "PV PBV", actual = "Raaj hello"
        self.assertNotEqual(expected_output, actual_output) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get the following error on running the test:

```
python -m unittest testearth.py 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_earth_working (testearth.TestEarth)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1183, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/u/pvmacibm/pooja/testearth.py", line 39, in test_earth_working
    mock_json_data = fh.read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 939, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1005, in _mock_call
    result = effect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 2352, in _read_side_effect
    return type(read_data)().join(_state[0])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'join'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s
```

Comment: The type hints should be `Foo` and `Bar`, not `Foo()` and `Bar()`.

Comment: If `Earth.__init__` takes `Foo` and `Bar` instances as *arguments*, rather than calling `Foo` and `Bar` itself, you wouldn't need to mock anything. If there's a reason for having `Earth.__init__` create the instances, at least have it take optional arguments that you can use for testing, rather than relying on `Earth.__init__` to create them.